# Django Formset.save() didn't save model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, firebird2.1

I'm replace save method with my own where I'm use cursor.callproc(prc,params), when i save form in Admin all just fine, but when i save formset just in view - nothing happen.

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    def save(self):
        proc_name="CLN_%s_EDIT" % self._meta.db_table
        ret=callproc(self,proc_name)
        if not ret:
            super(BaseModel,self).save()
    def delete(self):
        proc_name="CLN_%s_EDIT" % self._meta.db_table
        callproc(self,proc_name,'del')
    class Meta:
        abstract=True

def tarifs(request):
    TarifFormSet = modelformset_factory(TarifPlan)#,form=TarifPlanForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = TarifFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            #IPShellEmbed()()
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('')
            # do something.
        #else:
            #IPShellEmbed()()
    else:
        formset = TarifFormSet()
    c={"formset": formset,}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("tarifs.html",c)
```

Comment: Are you checking if the formset isn't valid?

Answer (score 1):

I guess your form isn't changed, and in [`formset.save_existing_objects()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L591) actual saving is being skipped.

Comment: When use super(BaseModel,self).save() all save just fine.

Comment: Then you can use something like `for form in formset.forms: if form.is_valid(): form.save()`

Answer (score 1):

Reading [this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) i found resolve this problem - just add

```
cursor.connection.commit()
```

after

```
cursor.callproc()
```